# No error shown in console when thrown from inside hapi plugin

Tags: hapi.js

For some reason no error shows up in the server console when I start my hapi server with nodemon and navigate to http://localhost:3000/hapi-ext-fetch and this makes debugging very difficult. Here is my code:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Joi = require('joi');
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

var debugMode = { debug: { request: [ 'error', 'request-internal' ] }};
var server = new Hapi.Server(debugMode);

server.connection({ port: 3000 });

var myPlugin = {
  register: function (server, options, next) {
    server.route([
      {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{name}',
        handler: function ( request, reply ) {
          throw new Error('this error isnt shown!');
        },
        config: {
          validate: {
            params: {
              name: Joi.string().min(3).max(10)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
    next();
  }
};

myPlugin.register.attributes = {
  name: 'myPlugin',
  version: '1.0.0'
};

server.register([
  {
    register: myPlugin,
    routes: {
      prefix: '/test'
    }
  }
], function() {
  server.ext( 'onPreResponse', ( request, reply ) => {
    if ( typeof request.response.statusCode !== 'undefined' ) {
      return reply.continue();
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/test/whatever')
    .then(function(result) {
      reply(result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      reply('error on server side: ' + err.stack);
    });
  });

  server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

I'm using hapi 13.0.0

Comment: Is that all your code? You're not starting the server or creating any connections?

Comment: This is the simplified version of my code. Running the hapi server is pretty trivial so I didn't include it here.

Comment: Issues on here are often down to trivial mistakes, so it's worth showing everything. Plus it makes it easier for us to help by running the same code you have.

Comment: There is so much code split between many files, putting all the code here is not feasible. So I made another plugin that has the same behavior as the real one.

Comment: That code looks really strange. So you're trying to hit a 404, catch it in an `onPreResponse`, then fire off another request in that to /test/whatever and then finally reply to the original 404 with the proxied error? Why?!

Comment: I'm doing server side rendering for the client in `onPreResponse` so it needs to hit 404 for the clientside router. Another request is fired during the rendering process inside `onPreResponse` to fetch required data for the client. I need to be able to see in the console any errors fired during data fetching, but none are shown as demonstrated by this code. Again, sorry for the confusion, but I doubt it would have made your life any easier if I had pasted all my code here, there **really** is a lot.

Comment: In your example `typeof request.response.statusCode` is always going to be undefined because it's always a Boom error (i.e. the 404 or the 500). So you'll be getting an infinite loop of requests, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I totally understand your use case here and if this question will be helpful to other people. But what you're trying to do it seems is:

- Send a request to /hapi-fetch-ext
- Have that request 404
- And then in an `onPreResponse` go fetch another route /test/whatever
- Hope to see the "this error isn't shown error"

Not sure if you're aware but this is going to cause an infinite cycle of requests (your fetch will cause another `onPreResponse` and so on and so on). So you should probably only go fetch on a 404:

```
server.ext( 'onPreResponse', ( request, reply ) => {

    if (request.response.isBoom && request.response.output.statusCode === 404) {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3000/test/whatever')
        .then(function(result) {
            reply(result);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            reply('error on server side: ' + err.stack);
        });
    }

    return reply.continue();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Sorry for not being able to post more code earlier. I have updated the code in the question. While it's still not 100% what I use in my real app, it behaves the same - I can't see the error in the console, only 404.